# web scraping using beautiful soup in django

Tags: django, web-scraping

This code is working fine. But i want to know how it is working .
Can anyone help me to explain this code??

> scraper.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


def scrape(url="https://www.onlinekhabar.com/2018/12/724699"):
    try:
        res = requests.get(url)
        # print(res.text)
        # print(res.encoding)
        res.encoding = "utf-8"
        bs = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")

        dict = {}
        dict["title"] = bs.select(".nws__title--card > h2")[0].text
        dict["published"] = bs.select(".post__time > span")[0].text
        dict["description"] = bs.select(".main__read--content")[0].text

        return dict
    except:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(scrape())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An XHR GET request is sent to the url via `requests` library. The response object html is handled by `BeautifulSoup.`

CSS selector syntax is used to retrieve information from the `BeautifulSoup` object generated.

`.nws__title--card`  is a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). Is selects for elements with class attribute `nws__title--card`. Then `>` is a [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) specifying that the `h2` tag elements on the right must be children of elements with the class specified on the left. The h2 is a [type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Type_selectors).

If you enter that selector in dev tools elements tab you will see there is only one match

[image]

So, this part

```
select(".nws__title--card > h2")
```

returns a list of all matched elements based upon the selector passed to `select` inside the "". Then

```
select(".nws__title--card > h2")[0]
```

selects for the first element. In this case, you can simply replace that with a method that returns only one match instead (then no index required):

```
select_one(".nws__title--card > h2")
```

h2 is a heading tag. It is getting the title from the page. That is then being added to the dictionary as the value pair for the `title` key

```
dict["title"]
```

Same logic applies for the other items being matched and added to the dictionary.

Either a dictionary is returned, if process succeeds, or `none` if fails.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score -1):

The request.get downloads the dom data for you and beautiful soup tags each data in the dom corresponding to their key/tag and creates a dictionary sort of a thing. So when you **bs.select(".nws__title--card > h2")**, this mean you are extracting data with tag **.nws__title--card > h2** which returns an array. Now you are selecting the first element in the array by doing **[0]** and requesting the text part. This is how it all works. For more detail read https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/.